# AngularJS http factory

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a code here and I just want to know the better one in getting data from php/mysql. Here are the codes:

**1. Using factory**

```
app.factory('todosFactory', function($http) {
    var factory = {};
    factory.getTodos = function() {
        return $http.get('todo-list.php');
    };
    return factory;
});

app.controller('ListController', function($scope, todosFactory, $http) {

    function init() {
        todosFactory.getTodos()
        .then(function successCallback(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
        }, function errorCallback(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    init();

});
```

**2. GET request directly in the controller**

```
app.controller('ListController', function($scope, $http) {
 //Init
    function init() {
        $http.get('todo-list.php')
        .then(function successCallback(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
        }, function errorCallback(data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
    }

    init();
});
```

Are there benefits of using one over the other? Thank you.

Comment: I use a factory, like your first example, because I use several controllers, and for each one, I simply put like a dependence and a parameter. And more, if any address change, I have only a single local to change. But, I recommend you to use ngResource, for more clean code for a factory of resources.

Comment: You can take a look in this [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-skinny-angularjs-controllers) for better clarification.

Comment: Several other benefits of factory is you can use a common error handler function for multiple API calls. Also makes it very simple to move the function call to a routing `resolve` if you need one

Comment: @charlietfl I'm a beginner in angular, and I really don't know which is the proper way to use. Or it really just depends on the project I am making? for now, just a simple rest

Comment: Don't worry about the `resolve` I mentioned....it's a way to have the data returned before the controller and template load, or to get data that the application needs before anything can proceed. Your factory looks fine and you can very easily add to it if you need to but it is the better of the two approaches you mentioned...even if you don't take advantage of that yet.

Comment: perhaps... If your code doesn't grow... you can to use the K.I.S.S. principle... and put all things on a single controller... we are talking about a project using angular. But, for curiosity, and to learn more about angular, you can create the factory anyway.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo LOL, my first time seeing that principle, googled and lol'ed

Comment: @charlietfl That sounds interesting, I will try that :)

Comment: Saw this https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide I think it would be beneficial

Comment: @FewFlyBy that particular style guide is one of the most common standards used in the angular community .. and defintiely the most quoted on this site

Answer (score 2):

FewFlyBy,

By all means it depends on how you will use it.

Taking a look at AngularJS: Up and Running pag. 88

> In case you have a RESTFUL API on your server, you can further reduce
>   the amount of code you write by using AngularJS’s optional module,
>   ngResource. ngResource allows us to take an API endpoint and create an
>   AngularJS service around it. For example, consider an API for projects
>   on the server side that behaves like the following:
>
> • GET request to /api/project/ returned an array of projects
>
> • GET request to /api/project/17 returned the project with ID 17
>
> • POST request to /api/project/ with a project object as JSON created
>   a new project
>
> • POST request to /api/project/19 with a project object as JSON
>   updated the project with ID 19
>
> • DELETE request to /api/project/ deleted all the projects
>
> • DELETE request to /api/project/23 deleted the project with ID 23
>
> If we have such an API, then instead of manually creating a project
>   resource, and wrapping up `$http` requests individually, we could just
>   create a service as follows:
>
> ```
> angular.module('resourceApp', ['ngResource'])
> .factory('ProjectService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
> return $resource('/api/project/:id');
> }]);
> ```
>
> This would automatically give us methods on ProjectService like: 
>   •`ProjectService.query()` to get a list of projects 
>   •`ProjectService.save({id: 15}, projectObj)` to update a project with
>   ID 15  •`ProjectService.get({id: 19})` to get an individual project
>   with ID 19

This basically means you can use your `$http` with `ngResource` to make your controller leaner yet having a powerful `.factory`. However, if you are you going to use it once, then you might just use it inside your controller.

Hope this is going to help you!

Comment: Thank you for this. Made ngResource much clearer for me.